# JPA DISTINCT, and Limiting result number

Tags: sql, jpa

I have a table like:

```
 Id crit1 crit2 value
 1  1     2     a
 2  2     2     b
 3  1     3     c
 4  1     1     d
 5  2     2     e
 6  1     2     f
```

for each combination of crit1 and crit2 i want the value with the highest Id. So the desired result is:

```
 crit1 crit2 value
 1     1     d
 1     2     f
 1     3     c
 2     2     e
```

How to define the query in JPA. (I tried DISTINCT, which would give all 6 datasets. If tried to limit it I only got 1 (not 4)).

Thanks!

Comment: add your tried code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a subquery grouping by `crit1` and `crit2` and get the max id of each group:

```
select max(e.id) from MyEntity e group by e.crit1, e.crit2
```

Then, you can create a query to show only the data required filtering by the IDs in the subquery:

```
select e.crit1, e.crit2, e.value 
from MyEntity e 
where e.id in (select max(sub.id) from MyEntity sub group by sub.crit1, sub.crit2)
order by e.crit1, e.crit2
```

Comment: its return wrong output.    "select max(sub.id) from MyEntity sub group by sub.id "  returns all Id here... which give you wrong result.

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale You are right, I explained the logic of the queries correctly but made a mistake and group by the id. It should group by `crit1` and `crit2`

Comment: Working now in my code. I'll mark this answer as selected solution, since it is more intuitive for me. @Mr Bohosale: Anyhow I'll investigate your solution as well, in order to learn more on the 'PARTITION BY' command. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @David SN.  ok. now ur query give you resuested o/p. also you can use 'order by crit1' which give you exact as expected result. thank u.

.@ BerndGit. sound good. you are marking answers without checking ? ok. No problem,
          if still if u have any concerns regarding answer plz let us know. thank u.

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale I added the `order by` to the query. Thx

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
            select crit1 ,crit2, value from 
            ( 
                select   crit1 ,crit2, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION  BY crit1 , crit2 
                ORDER BY id desc ) as rank from #table_name t
            )a where a.rank=1
```

Comment: Trying this in my code i got. `line 1:31: unexpected token: OVER`. based on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74057/is-it-possible-to-use-analytic-functions-in-hibernate I supect that the `PARTITION` command is not nativly supported but needs to be imported to JPA before using it. Correct?